# Amazon Ec2 Outgoing Sockets (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can't seem to be able to have Aws ec2 machines send outgoing socket communications. I allowed all traffic, turned of the firewall, and set a Elasitic I.P nothing is working. I'm using a python socket for simplicity. I'm able to listen and receive connections although then send data to that connection find. But whenever I try to connect I get a timeout. I searched far and wide for a answer to this question and none match my issue.